# Configuring subdomains in Eclipse PDT & xDebug

Tags: php, eclipse, subdomain, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to set up a local environment for developing and testing an existing PHP application.

I've chosen Eclipse PDT as my IDE and xDebug as the debugging module. When testing individual files on the server's document root, things work perfectly. However, certain folders in my project need to resolve as subdomains when running the debugger:

/index.php -> *hostname/index.php*
/control/index.php -> *control.hostname/index.php*
/support/a/b.php -> *support.hostname/a/b.php*

Is there any way to accomplish this kind of set up? I've tried using path mappings under the PHP Server settings, but it doesn't seem to affect the URL Eclipse generates when I start debugging.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup one webserver per subdomain and then do the path mapping according to it.

Start the debug session with the fitting webserver setting then.

Comment: Debug Configurations -> New for all 3 domains and subdomains ;-)

Answer (score -1):

After create your virtual host make sure you can access it at browser URL.