# Eclipse PHP Xdebug for Document Root as project subdir

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have a `PHP` project in `Eclipse PDT`, which I want to debug using `Xdebug` remotely. I use a `SSH` tunnel for the debugger i.e., `Eclipse` uses a local port. Although this might seem complex, it runs nicely for 2 other projects, and I can attach `dbgpClient` for the problematic setup. Also `Eclipse` changes to debugging when I trigger it on the external web server i.e., `Xdebug` seems to properly attach to `Eclipse`.

As with the other projects I set up project specific PHP debug settings:

```
Base Path:  /
Base URL:   http://project.example.com/
checked:    Break at First Line
PHP Server: Project (Debugger Xdebug)
  Server
   Base URL:      http://project.example.com/
   Document Root: /local/project/root/web
  Debugger
   Debugger:      Xdebug
   Port:          tunneled port on localhost
  Path Mapping
   Server:        /remote/project/root
   Local:         /local/project/root
```

However, the working projects all have `index.php` in the project root. The non-working project has `index.php` in `/project/root/web`, and the web-server has set the document root to that very directory. Also, `/remote/project/root` and `/local/project/root` are different here, but identical for the other 2 projects. I also played around with variations of these settings, but I always came to the same result.

`Eclipse` seems unable to map the path sent by `Xdebug` to any path in the workspace i.e., the behavior is identical to debugging a file missing in the workspace. The page is delivered without any break in `Eclipse`, but I see the red `stop debugging` button appear. I see the data sent to the browser in `Debug Output`.

Is there any guidance what all these settings mean? I.e. I guess I get something wrong, here. Is there some log file to check how `Eclipse` maps filenames received via the `Xdebug` port to filenames in the workspace?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586060/eclipse-xdebug-pdt-not-able-to-map-path-correctly) seems to address a similar issue, but also has no solution. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966242/configuring-subdomains-in-eclipse-pdt-xdebug?rq=2) at least hints at that my approach is not entirely wrong, but it does not state, what correct configuration means.

**Update:** If I chose `/remote/project/root` and `/local/project/root` to be identical i.e. by moving the directory on the server, the everything is just fine. So it seems that the Path Mapping does not do what I expect it to do and how I understood [the docs](https://eclipse.dev/pdt/help/html/path_mapping.htm). Is this a bug, or am I just ignorant?